# blist install : error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1 - for python3.10.6 in Ubuntu 22.04.3

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to install the python module blist but always get this compiling error:

`error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1`

The recommended solution is to reassure that all the necessary headers are available by running

`sudo apt install python3-dev`

in the terminal. This solution does not work for me. Any other ideas?

Thank you in advance!

---

**Long error output:**

```
***@***:~$ pip3 install blist
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting blist
  Using cached blist-1.3.6.tar.gz (122 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: blist
  Building wheel for blist (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [35 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/blist
      copying blist/_sorteddict.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/blist
      copying blist/_btuple.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/blist
# copying blist/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/blist
      copying blist/_sortedlist.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/blist
      running build_ext
      building 'blist._blist' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/blist
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -DBLIST_FLOAT_RADIX_SORT=1 -I/usr/include/python3.10 -c blist/_blist.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/blist/_blist.o
      blist/_blist.c: In function ‘unwrap_leaf_array’:
      blist/_blist.c:4583:37: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘_PyObject_GC_IS_TRACKED’; did you mean ‘PyObject_GC_IsTracked’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
       4583 |                 if (leafs_n > 1 && !_PyObject_GC_IS_TRACKED(leafs[i]))
            |                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            |                                     PyObject_GC_IsTracked
      blist/_blist.c: In function ‘sort_ulong’:
      blist/_blist.c:5387:31: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘Py_ssize_t’ {aka ‘long int’} and ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wsign-compare]
       5387 |                 for (j = 0; j < NUM_PASSES; j++) {
            |                               ^
      blist/_blist.c:5393:31: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘Py_ssize_t’ {aka ‘long int’} and ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wsign-compare]
       5393 |                 for (j = 0; j < NUM_PASSES; j++) {
            |                               ^
      blist/_blist.c:5403:23: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘Py_ssize_t’ {aka ‘long int’} and ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wsign-compare]
       5403 |         for (j = 0; j < NUM_PASSES; j++) {
            |                       ^
      blist/_blist.c: In function ‘py_blist_sort’:
      blist/_blist.c:6592:27: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
       6592 |         Py_REFCNT(&saved) = 1;
            |                           ^
      error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for blist
  Running setup.py clean for blist
Failed to build blist
ERROR: Could not build wheels for blist, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```